# Notification and Request permission function not working for Android Studio Android 6.0

Tags: android-studio, android-notifications, android-permissions

I'm building an application using Java in Android Studio [Android 6.0]. I want the user allow permissions and receive a notification on booting up the application but the current code I have is not working. Shown below:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class gamer_login_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private void createNotificationChannel() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "login channel";
            String description = "channel for bootup notifications";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("muffet", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gamer_login_page);

//-------------notify the user that they have entered the app
        createNotificationChannel();

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.hypnos)
                .setContentTitle("Welcome")
                .setContentText("You have booted up Forked Decisions Alpha. I hope your time here is satisfactory!")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, gamer_login_page.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

//-------------notification over
```

The manifest file contains `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"></uses-permission>` but isn't requesting the permission from the user on boot up.
Could you tell me how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Check for notification permission on app launch, and if the permission is not granted, it will either show a rationale dialog to explain why the permission is needed or directly request the permission. If the user denies the permission, they will be prompted to open the app settings to manually grant the permission.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation about Runtime Permissions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) also check permission samples on GitHub [here](https://github.com/android/platform-samples/tree/main/samples/privacy/permissions)
Good luck